# How to select next value just after a particular value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, row-number

[image]
[image]

I want to select values which is just after the stat = idle

Comment: Can you explain more details about question? Please provide table structure , sample data and expected output in text format.

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as 
 (
    select *,
       case when lag(stat,1,'idle') over (order by time) = 'idle' -- previous row is idle
             and stat <> 'idle'                                   -- current row is not idle
            then 1
            else 0
       end as flag 
    from tab
 )
select * from cte
where flag = 1
```

This return the first row, too, if you want to exclude it, remove the default from `lag`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query using lag as shown below

```
create table #temp (id int identity (1,1), times datetime, gps_speed decimal(18,2),I2 int, stat varchar(20), row_num int)
insert into #temp values 
('2018-12-14', 18.52, 1, 'running', 4),
('2018-12-14', 0, 1, 'idle', 5),
('2018-12-14', 24.08, 1, 'running', 6),
('2018-12-14', 37.04, 1, 'running', 29),
('2018-12-14', 0, 1, 'idle', 30),
('2018-12-14', 0, 1, 'idle', 32),
('2018-12-14', 18.52, 1, 'running', 37),
('2018-12-14', 35.19, 1, 'running', 41),
('2018-12-14', 16.67, 1, 'running', 42),
('2018-12-14', 0, 1, 'idle', 43),
('2018-12-14', 0, 1, 'idle', 44)    

select * from (
select 
      lag(stat, 1) OVER(ORDER BY [id]) as Prev,*
from #temp
)a where Prev <> stat
and Prev = 'idle' or Prev is null
```

The output is as shown below

```
Prev    id  times   gps_speed           I2  stat     row_num
NULL    1   14.12.2018 00:00:00 18,52   1   running  4
idle    3   14.12.2018 00:00:00 24,08   1   running  6
idle    7   14.12.2018 00:00:00 18,52   1   running  37
```

Here is the live demo - [**Demo <> Prev Value**](https://rextester.com/CCVBSM75386)

Comment: You can replace * with actual column name which are select times, gps_speed, I2, stat, row_num from (... Find the revised demo here - https://rextester.com/WEP9020

Answer (score -1):

```
        SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE   
        ROWNUM>ANY(SELECT  
         Max(ROWNUM)
         FROM TABLE WHERE 
        STATUS='IDLE')
```

This should work i guess to get the desired meaning the outer query is working row by row and the subquery is returning the rownum just when it gets status as idle

Comment: This is equivalent to `WHERE   
        ROW_NUM>(SELECT  
         min(ROW_NUM) 
         FROM TABLE WHERE 
        STATUS='IDLE')`and will return *all* rows after `row_num 5`

Comment: min() or max() i guess getting max() of rownum for that record would do it as the value which is the final idle the OP requires the next to it always but even i am not getting will it work as desired or to use a corerelated subquery as in my approach i thought of having a outer query running rowbyrow and within the inside a subquery which will have status idle whenever this outer queries row by row operation matches with the subquery result then give the next rownum's output that status other than idle

Comment: agreed dnoeth was trying to have it performed the same operation again and again ended up into something not desired thanks!